# cImage python module error

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm writing a function to convert and display an image to negative, when i call the function i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Librophyton/Procdeimagenes/test.py",line 32, in <module>
makeNegative(dude)
File "C:\Python34\lib\ImageProcess.py", line 16, in makeNegative
old = FileImage(imageFile)
File "C:\Python34\lib\cImage.py", line 398, in __init__
super(FileImage, self).__init__(fname = thefile)
File "C:\Python34\lib\cImage.py", line 241, in __init__
self.loadImage(fname)
File "C:\Python34\lib\cImage.py", line 270, in loadTkImage
sufstart = fname.rfind('.')
AttributeError: 'FileImage' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Here is the function:

```
def makeNegative(imageFile):

window = ImageWin("Proceso de imagen", 1000-100, 900)
old = FileImage(imageFile)
old.draw(window)
window.exitOnClick()

w = old.getWidth()
h = old.getHeight()
new = EmptyImage(w,h)

for row in range(h):

    for col in range(w):

        pixelviejo = old.getPixel(col,row)
        pixelnuevo = pixelNeg(pixelviejo)
        new.setPixel(col, row, pixelnuevo)
new.setPosition(w+1, 0)
new.draw(window)
window.exitOnClick()
```

And here is the funciton call:

```
dude = FileImage("factores_de_conversion.gif" )
makeNegative(dude)
```

Any idea how to solve this? or how should i modify the module?

Comment: What is `FileImage`? The code for this would be useful, as the error relates to FileImage class.

Comment: I found this in the module:

    `class FileImage(AbstractImage):`
     def __init__(self,thefile):
        `super(FileImage, self).__init__(fname = thefile)`